# Returning errors in Web API : error integer codes or error strings?

Tags: javascript, json, api, asp.net-web-api, error-handling

I have a question regarding returning errors inside web API. This web API is called usually from javascript (a website).
There are two possibilities of returning errors, the one is returning them as a string, and the other is returning them as integer error code.

An example JSON of returning errors as error codes :

```
{
    "status" : "Error",
    "error"  : 30
}
```

An example JSON of returning errors as error strings :

```
{
    "status" : "Error",
    "error"  : "ERR_INVALID_FILENAME"
}
```

What do you think is the best approach? I'm thinking that the error strings choice is better, because of the following :

- The error strings choice improves code readability and maintainability, by inducing a self commenting code.
  Since, while in the error code approach, the javascript dev would write :

  `if (result.error == 30) { do something related to files and invalidness...}`

  in the error string approach, the javascript dev would write :

  `if (result.error == "ERR_INVALID_FILENAME") { do something related to files and invalidness...}`
- in the grand scheme of things, browser rendering, HTML dom manipulation, and AJAX HTTP request processing, this little error string check is insignificant overhead. While in a C++ or C# app we obviously would use an enum, we do not have such a choice in two separate entities such as web api and a website, and the cost payoff seems reasonable.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I agree with what you say but this question might fit better in the software engineering community.

Comment: @Itay Did you reach any solution ?

Comment: @JoseFrancis With only two opinions, I wish there were more answers to this question. 
One additional extra input I've thought about the recent days is that in the API, the errors (even if they are stringified when they are JSONified) should reside in an enum and it should be strongly typed (so that it can be checked in compile time).

Answer (score 0):

1. I you have same error message for multiple request maybe you can use some kind of structutre for error enum, dictionary, even list (if you need multilanguge).
2. You can have some kind of translator from error code to message(even type, level). There are many situations when you will need more then a message: maybe you will have a freindly message and a debug message, maybe you need somekind of types to say that is a blocking msg and that is an warning only.
3. You may send error as a string to client and your json size will be increased (depends of massage length) or you can have preload errors map in js and convert code to message there, you message if will be smaller (again depends) but you client side will work to do that. Be aware of browser memory  limits when you move to js.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question of  "string or integer error codes", **string option is preferable and good enough** in the code perspective and apart from that **handling errors and displaying proper messages in JS could not be accounted as a cost or overhead**.

As an improvement, I would suggest that you could send proper HTTP status codes like `200 for success and 400 for bad request` etc. for generic purpose use in the whole application.

If you want the client application to detect a specific error coming in from the API you can include your model containing the error status and code inside the "data part" of your `HttpResponseMessage()`, so that you don't have to always check the error code.